# PHP web socket not connect in SSL

Tags: php, websocket, wss

I am trying to connect **PHP web socket** using **WSS**.

- **took code reference from below link**

https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket

- **it shows error as below**

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://php.fmv.cc:12345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

- **server configuration as below**

[image]

[image]

- **these are the links on which I am trying**

http://php.fmv.cc/c2.php (ws)

https://php.fmv.cc/c3.php (wss)

this will try to connect socket at : **ws://php.fmv.cc:12345/** and **wss://php.fmv.cc:12345/**

Thank you...

Comment: try with default port 8080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello On the server configuration make setting like below

```
ProxyPass /wss/ ws://127.0.0.1:12345/
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ ws://127.0.0.1:12345/
```

and on client side you can connect it using your domain don't mentioned port with it.

> use like wss://php.fmv.cc/wss